# use of deleted function ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++ code with multiple files. I use g++-4.8 as my compiler with Ubuntu 18.04. Upon compiling the program I face the error below. Could you please help me to fix this?

> use of deleted function 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::_basic_ofstream<char>)'

I did not have this error, however by adding `emplace_back()` to code this error showed up:

```
#include "FileOutputHub.h"

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include "InitialCondition.h"

using namespace std;

const char* LogFileName = "simulation_log.txt";
const char* StatsFilePrefix = "stats_";
const char* QSP_prefix = "QSP_";
const char* OdeStatsFilePrefix = "odeStats_";
const char* SnapShotDir = "/snapShots";
const char* SaveStateDir = "/savedStates";

extern InitialCondition ic;

FileOutputHub::FileOutputHub(void)
: _seed()
, _outDirBase()
, _log()
, _generalStats_core()
, _generalStats_margin()
, _lymph_blood_QSP()
, _gridSnapshotFstream()
, _makeshiftSteam()
{
}

FileOutputHub::~FileOutputHub()
{
    _log.close();
    for (auto& fs : _generalStats_core) {
        fs.close();
    }
    for (auto& fs : _generalStats_margin) {
        fs.close();
    }
}

/*!
    Process paths and setup output file streams
    \param [in] seed: seed is used as part of the ABM/ODE stats file names
    \param [in] baseDirectory: base directory for all output files

    Simulation log file is saved in the base directory. If a new simulation's output
    directory is set to be the same as an older one, new log will append to the end of
    existing log.

    ABM/ODE stats are placed inside the base directory, which has a file name including
    the seed of the simulation. If output directory exists, stats will be attached to
    existing files. This is because when loading from a saved state, if the seed is the same,
    we assume the simulation is continuation of the saved progress, and append statas to
    the end of existing stats file without writing new headers; otherwise, new header is writen,
    so output directory should be set to a new location.

    all grid snapshot output file are placed in a sub-folder "snapShots".

    all serialization (saved states) are placed in a sub-folder "savedStates".
    */
void FileOutputHub::setup(long seed, string baseDirectory){

    _seed = seed;
    _outDirBase = baseDirectory;
    
    // create directories
    boost::filesystem::path pSnap(_outDirBase + SnapShotDir);
    boost::filesystem::create_directories(pSnap);// create snapshot directory tree
    
    boost::filesystem::path pState(_outDirBase + SaveStateDir);
    boost::filesystem::create_directories(pState);// create save states directory tree

    // initialize filestreams
    string logFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + LogFileName;
    _log.open(logFileName, ios::out | ios::app);


    string statsFileName;
    for (int i = 0; i < ic.getVal(IC_NUM_ROI_core); i++) {

        _generalStats_core.emplace_back(ofstream());
        statsFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + StatsFilePrefix + "core_" 
            + to_string(i) + "_s_" + to_string(_seed) + ".csv";
        //std::cout << "file: " << i << ", " <<statsFileName << std::endl;
        _generalStats_core[i].open(statsFileName, ios::out | ios::app);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ic.getVal(IC_NUM_ROI_margin); i++) {
        _generalStats_margin.emplace_back(ofstream());
        statsFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + StatsFilePrefix + "margin_" 
            + to_string(i) + "_s_" + to_string(_seed) + ".csv";
        //std::cout << "file: " << i << ", " <<statsFileName << std::endl;
        _generalStats_margin[i].open(statsFileName, ios::out | ios::app);
    }

    string QSP_FileName = _outDirBase + "/" + QSP_prefix + to_string(_seed) + ".csv";
    _lymph_blood_QSP.open(QSP_FileName, ios::out | ios::app);

}


ofstream& FileOutputHub::getStatsFstream(bool core, int i){ 
    if (core)
    {
        return _generalStats_core[i]; 
    }
    else{
        return _generalStats_margin[i]; 
    }
}
/*! Create a new output file stream for grid snapshot and return the pointer
    \param [in] time: used to time stamp the file name
    \param [in] tag: goes to first part of file name 
    use case:
    std::ofstream * snap;
    snap = <FileOutputHub instance>.getNewGridToSnapshot(time, tag);
    *snap << [contents] << std::endl;
    snap->close();
*/
ofstream& FileOutputHub::getNewGridToSnapshotStream(unsigned long time, std::string tag){

    string gridSnapFileName = _outDirBase + SnapShotDir+ "/" + tag + to_string(time) + ".csv";
    _gridSnapshotFstream.open(gridSnapFileName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    return _gridSnapshotFstream;
}

/*! Create a new output file stream for serialzation and return the pointer
    \param [in] time: used to time stamp the file name
    \param [in] tag: goes to first part of file name 
    use case:
    std::ofstream * pState;
    pState = <FileOutputHub instance>.getNewSaveStateStream(time, tag);
    *pState << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(item1) << [item2] ...;
    pState->close();
    note that the NVP macro uses the variable name as xml tag; if want to use a different 
    name, use boost::serialization::make_nvp("tag", variable)
*/
ofstream& FileOutputHub::getNewSaveStateStream(unsigned long time, std::string tag){
    string saveStateFileName = _outDirBase + SaveStateDir+ "/" + tag + to_string(time) + ".dat";
    _saveStateStream.open(saveStateFileName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    return _saveStateStream;
}

/*!
    Create a new output file stream for temporary and general purposes
    \Param [in] tag: file name
    use case:
    std::ofstream * pOFS;
    pOFS = <output overseer instance>.getNewMakeshiftStream(tag);
    *pOFS << ...
    pOFS->CLOSE()
*/
ofstream& FileOutputHub::getNewMakeshiftStream(std::string tag){

    string makeShiftFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + tag;
    _makeshiftSteam.open(makeShiftFileName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    return _makeshiftSteam;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory -- you're trying to use the copy ctor for basic_ofstream which is not copyable.  The error message should tell you where this is happening -- probably in trying to copy some class object that has an ofstream member.

Comment: what do you expect this `emplace_back(ofstream())` to do?

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete and contains too much extraneous information, but presumably `_generalStats_core` contains a collection of `ofstream`s (or objects that contain one).    The call `_generalStats_core.ofstream()` attempts to COPY an `ofstream`, which is not allowed.    To increase chances of getting a more useful/specific response, read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a compiler bug.

Assuming the containers are e.g. `std::vector`s, `.emplace_back(ofstream())` should be calling the move constructor of `ofstream` to construct the new vector element in-place from the temporary object created by `ofstream()`.

Apparently your compiler version tries to use the copy constructor, but `ofstream` isn't copyable.

With GCC 5.1 or later it works are expected: https://godbolt.org/z/KKWKvx65a

I suggest you get a more up-to-date compiler. GCC 4.8 is very old and just barely even supports C++11.

Comment: I used GCC 7.5 and the problem was not solved.

Comment: @Mehdi Then please provide a proper [mre] including the full output of the compiler. `.emplace_back(ofstream())` works since GCC 5.1 and also with GCC 7.5 as you can check in the compiler explorer link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`emplace_back()` creates a new object in-place in the container, passing its constructor the input parameters passed to `emplace_back()`.

In `FileOutputHub::setup()`, your 2 loops are creating a temporary `ofstream` object and passing it to `emplace_back()`, so it will try to create a new element passing that temporary `ofstream` to the new element's constructor.

It is clear from the error message that `_generalStats_core` and `_generalStats_margin` are holding `ofstream` elements, and your compiler is trying to call `ofstream`'s copy constructor instead of its move constructor, so this will not work, as C++ streams are not copyable, only movable.

However, `ofstream` has a constructor that accepts the same input parameters as its `open()` method, so the loops can be re-written to not create the temporary `ofstream` objects at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ic.getVal(IC_NUM_ROI_core); i++) {
    statsFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + StatsFilePrefix + "core_" 
        + to_string(i) + "_s_" + to_string(_seed) + ".csv";
    //std::cout << "file: " << i << ", " << statsFileName << std::endl;
    _generalStats_core.emplace_back(statsFileName, ios::app);
}

for (int i = 0; i < ic.getVal(IC_NUM_ROI_margin); i++) {
    statsFileName = _outDirBase + "/" + StatsFilePrefix + "margin_" 
        + to_string(i) + "_s_" + to_string(_seed) + ".csv";
    //std::cout << "file: " << i << ", " << statsFileName << std::endl;
    _generalStats_margin.emplace_back(statsFileName, ios::app);
}
```

Comment: @user17732522 Apparently it is a compiler bug, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71027187/65863)

Comment: This did not work for me and I can see the same error